# Why the result won't be the same when I change the && condition:

Tags: c++, linked-list

[Finding middle element in a linked list](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/finding-middle-element-in-a-linked-list/1?utm_source=gfg&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=bottom_sticky_on_article)

Given a singly linked list of N nodes.
The task is to find the middle of the linked list. For example, if the linked list is
1-> 2->3->4->5, then the middle node of the list is 3.
If there are two middle nodes(in case, when N is even), print the second middle element.
For example, if the linked list given is 1->2->3->4->5->6, then the middle node of the list is 4.

Example 1:

Input:
LinkedList: 1->2->3->4->5
Output: 3
Explanation:
Middle of linked list is 3.
Example 2:

Input:
LinkedList: 2->4->6->7->5->1
Output: 7
Explanation:
Middle of linked list is 7.
Your Task:
The task is to complete the function getMiddle() which takes a head reference as the only argument and should return the data at the middle node of the linked list.

Expected Time Complexity: O(N).
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1).

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 5000

```
class Solution{
    public:
    /* Should return data of middle node. If linked list is empty, then  -1*/
    int getMiddle(Node *head)
    {
        Node* fast = head;
        Node *slow = head;
        
        if (head != NULL){
            while(fast->next != NULL && fast != NULL) //here
            {
                fast = fast->next->next;
                slow = slow->next;
            }
        }
        
        return slow->data;
    }
};

// Runtime Error: Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
```

```
class Solution{
    public:
    /* Should return data of middle node. If linked list is empty, then  -1*/
    int getMiddle(Node *head)
    {
        Node* fast = head;
        Node *slow = head;
        
        if (head != NULL){
            while(fast != NULL && fast->next != NULL) //here
            {
                fast = fast->next->next;
                slow = slow->next;
            }
        }
        
        return slow->data;
    }
};

// Problem Solved Successfully
```

Comment: `&&` is checked left to right. If `fast == NULL`, `fast->next` is illegal and crashes, so it must be checked after making sure `fast` isn't null.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] for both of your examples. As these are now, they can't be compiled for introspection.

Comment: Because that's how `&&` works. Where are you learning C++ from that didn't tell you this? Maybe you should find some better teaching material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `while(fast->next != NULL && fast != NULL)` makes no sense. If `fast` does equal `NULL` then `fast->next` is undefined. The only way this can be "ok" is when `fast` is not `NULL`.

In the second first you first check if `fast` equals `NULL` and due to short cuirciting of `&&` only when it is not equal it is dereferenced.

Comment: But surely the point is that the OP does not know about short circuiting